# Why can't spoofed caller ID's be identified?

Tags: phone, spoofing

There are several posts here about how easy it is to spoof caller ID and that there is no way to detect it.

I did find one post suggesting the calls to 1-800 numbers could not be spoofed.

> being done by forwarding calls to a toll-free number, which then (by virtue of being toll-free) receives the true calling number through ANI (which is distinct from Caller ID and which supposedly cannot be spoofed) and finally forwards back to the original number. [Source](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/81206/24064)

**Question:
Why can't spoofed caller ID's be identified for everyone?**

---

**Related posts:**

- [How can caller ID be faked?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211778/24064)
- [How can I spoof a phone call and make it appear to come from another phone?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36986/24064)
- [Why is caller ID spoofing so simple, and catching offenders so hard?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/175856/24064)
- [How to protect from caller-id spoofing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/84302/24064)
- [Is there any way to detect caller ID spoofing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/81166/24064)

Comment: That assumption about toll-free numbers is wrong. Yes, ANI is distinct from Caller ID, but ANI can be spoofed on toll-free calls. In fact, in certain cases it's easier to do that than on non-toll free calls. Caller ID and ANI can't really be trusted at all, 100% of the time.

Answer (score 4):

There are substantial flaws in the way phone routing works that makes this difficult.

Caller ID is specified by the outgoing call and anybody who has control over a [private branch exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_telephone_system#Private_branch_exchange) (PBX) can mess with it. (This is a "feature" so e.g. a support center can always have the same callback number as opposed to the number of the associate calling you.) I believe there is some limited ability to traverse the call routing, but that stops as soon as it hits a [voice-over-IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) (VoIP) provider, which effectively provide a screen akin to reputation hijacking (an attacker gets lost in the noise of a shared pool of resources).

(I assume most spam calls come from VoIP, though my spam expertise is limited to email.)

Happily, the US (as of [2021-06-30](https://www.fcc.gov/document/mandating-stirshaken-combat-spoofed-robocalls-0)) and Canada (as of [2021-11-30](https://crtc.gc.ca/eng/archive/2021/2021-123.htm)) now require [**STIR/SHAKEN**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STIR/SHAKEN), "a suite of protocols and procedures intended to combat caller ID spoofing".

From the FCC's [news release PDF](https://docs.fcc.gov/public/attachments/DOC-363399A1.pdf):

> **FCC MANDATES THAT PHONE COMPANIES IMPLEMENT CALLER ID AUTHENTICATION TO COMBAT SPOOFED ROBOCALLS**
>
> ***Industry-wide Deployment of STIR/SHAKEN Will Yield Substantial Benefits for American Consumers***
>
> WASHINGTON, March 31, 2020—The Federal
> Communications Commission today adopted new rules requiring
> implementation of caller ID authentication using technical standards
> known as “STIR/SHAKEN.”  These rules will further the FCC’s efforts to
> protect consumers against malicious caller ID “spoofing,” which is
> often used during robocall scam campaigns to trick consumers into
> answering their phones.
>
> …

With strict limitations on Caller ID forgery, spammer blocklists become feasible.

This also hopefully gives more teeth to the US [National Do Not Call Registry](https://www.donotcall.gov/), forwarding spam texts to [7726](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_spam#Defense) (which is still quite [tedious](https://twitter.com/adamhotep/status/1450879667217514500)), the 1991 [Telephone Consumer Protection Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_Consumer_Protection_Act), and newer [proposals](https://www.fcc.gov/document/acting-chair-rosenworcel-proposes-rules-combat-rise-robotexts).