# How can I test if/how STIR/SHAKEN is working on my incoming calls? Both for detecting spoofed caller ID AND [bad sources]

Tags: penetration-test, spam, phone, fraud, debugging

How can I test if/how STIR/SHAKEN is working on my incoming calls?  Both for detecting spoofed caller ID AND calls from disreputable (NON-'A' attestation) service providers/carriers/sources.

I'm looking for something vaguely like  https://www.internetbadguys.com/ , https://dnsleak.com , [OpenDNS/Cisco Umbrella list](https://support.umbrella.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000411528-What-are-the-Umbrella-Test-Destinations) ... 1-800-MY-ANI-IS (which, sadly, no longer works and is now a sleazy marketer), ...

I'm getting a ton of harassing, spoofed phone calls, and the bulk of them appear to be criminal enterprises discussed [in this FCC filing](https://ecfsapi.fcc.gov/file/10622280311488/Consumer%20Comments%20on%20Assurance%20Petition.pdf).  My phone #s are all already on [do not call lists](https://800notes.com/faq/state-do-not-call), such as https://www.donotcall.gov/.  I'm already using a HiYa-based anti spam call app.

Relevant/research so far:

- On SE: [Why can't spoofed caller ID's be identified?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/226946/why-cant-spoofed-caller-ids-be-identified/229153)
- https://www.home.neustar/blog/att-and-neustar-execs-share-thoughts-on-stir-shaken-success. *Excerpts* :
- I know https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov is there
- https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/the-tcpa-protection-against-robo-calls-prerecorded-calls.html is good.
- TCPA small claims suits are effective; may be time for another one:
- [Screwing telemarketers for fun and profit](https://web.mit.edu/bjaspan/www/tcpa/tcpa.html) (MIT.edu)

> "Overseeing STIR/SHAKEN implementation is the Secure Telephone
> Identity Governance Authority (STI-**G**A), a governing body comprising
> service providers representing every segment of the industry, as well
> as an administrator, and a technical committee. This board sets up the
> Policy Administrators (**P**As) that authorize service providers' ability
> to get a token and approve certificates to make sure calls can be
> authenticated and exchanged with other carriers.
>
> To date, **fifty-five** service providers have registered with the STI-**P**A
> to be able to sign their calls with STIR/SHAKEN authentication.
>
> Approximately 15 [major] carriers publicly announced they’re deploy**ing** STIR/SHAKEN in parts of their network [=] 70% of all active phone numbers in the U.S.
>
> Neustar [provides] the ATIS Robocalling Testbed.
>
> ATIS serves as the industry interoperability test facility to validate the effectiveness of caller authentication standards developed by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) and ATIS.

...

> “STIR/SHAKEN will only confirm that a call is not spoofed,” said Linda

(I think this is false/misleading.)

> Specifically, the working group **recommended** monitoring subscriber traffic patterns to identify behaviors consistent with illegal robocalling and take action when illegal robocalling campaigns are identified.

> [E]nterprises can let < sic > consumers which calls to trust

> provid[e] more context and identif[y] details on legitimate phone calls, along with a check mark that shows the call has been authenticated

I feel I'm getting far MORE spoofed and spam phone calls since STIR/SHAKEN has gone into effect.  This year, the number of spam SMS has gone from none for months to multiple per week.

---

Comment: I'm more than willing to block all calls from the kickers & screamers.  Also, what you're saying isn't current. They wrote 3 months ago, "We've successfully deployed the key components of STIR / SHAKEN in production and formally announced our initial carrier interop with Verizon Wireless in a December 11, 2019 press release. Our current SHAKEN implementation is as defined in ATIS 1000074" plus, "the new TRACED Act that was signed into law mandates that Service Providers have STIR / SHAKEN deployed by June 30, 2021." Most carriers are kicking & screaming while pretending to be in favor. IMNHO.

Comment: Also, your comment serves to show that my question is important and timely, though it doesn't help answer it.

Comment: I work in the VoIP industry.  It's great that Verizon has implemented it on their end, but stir/shaken needs to be implemented across the board, on all/most carriers for it to be effective. What I'm telling you is that the majority of VoIP traffic being directed into the PSTN has no Stir/Shaken attestation.  Maybe they can distinguish some verizon numbers as geniune, or maybe some other wireless carriers, but it says nothing about any other traffic entering their network.

Comment: From what you’ve mentioned, it is clear to me I know more about at least some aspects of stir/shaken, including deployment, than you do.

Comment: Please try writing in English and skip the straw man attack.

Comment: You are not worth  talking to.